# Does git pull change HEAD?

Tags: git

I understand how git checkout changes the HEAD pointer but what about git pull?

HEAD can be seen as the 'current branch' but when you execute git pull and your current branch is altered. Does it affect HEAD pointer? Why?

Comment: HEAD is a reference to the tip of the current branch, so if the `git pull` you ran brought in new commits on top of your branch, then yes, pulling can move the HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `HEAD` is a double-indirection to a commit. `git checkout` manipulates the first indirection, `git commit`, `git merge`, `git pull` and other commands the second.

Example: After `git checkout master` the file `.git/HEAD` contains

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

which is a "symbolic reference" to a branch ref (see `git help symbolic-ref`). Doing `git checkout develop` gives you

```
ref: refs/heads/develop
```

`git pull` (which is either `git fetch; git merge` or `git fetch; git rebase`) will not touch the `.git/HEAD` but manipulate `.git/refs/heads/master` (and/or `git./packed-refs`).

So the answer is: `git pull` does not manipulate `HEAD` but the ref `HEAD` points to. The effect is that `HEAD` points to another commit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

> More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to "merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch".

Note : The double quotes have been added by me for highlighting.

---

> Does it affect HEAD pointer?

Yes, if newer commits have been pulled.

> Why?

Because the HEAD refers to the most recent commit. As you have pulled latest changes (read commits), the HEAD has to refer to the newer commits pulled.

Comment: And you could say the same thing for git merge, right? As long as your current branch is altered.

Comment: Yes. After merging, the new 'merged' HEAD is head of the branches being merged.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it affect HEAD pointer?

It's easy to find out for yourself. In you local clone of some git repo, create a new branch (so that you can mess around without endangering any of your work), and make sure that it's up to date with the remote:

```
git checkout -b test-branch
git pull
```

Next, take a look at HEAD in that branch:

```
git log
```

Note the value of HEAD, which is the most recent commit. Now change HEAD using the `reset` command to go back a few commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Now you've intentionally changed HEAD -- that's what `reset` *does*. The synopsis of the `reset` command is: *Reset current HEAD to the specified state*. That is, you've just gone back in time to 3 commits before the latest commit. Let's look at HEAD again:

```
git log
```

You can see that HEAD has changed from what it was before. Now, use `pull` to add the "new" commits from the remote back to your branch, and look again at HeAD:

```
git pull
git log
```

You should see that HEAD is back to where it was before the `reset`, and this should show you that `git pull` does change HEAD and why.

HEAD isn't special for any reason other than being a name for the latest commit. Anything you do that changes what `git` sees as the latest commit in your branch changes the value of HEAD.